# Ao alterar um determinado status, ele altera de todos

Tags: jquery

Como eu posso fazer para que o usuário ao clicar em **Pendente**, o status mudar para **Pago**? Vejam:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou fazendo da seguinte forma:

**PHP**

```
    while($csClientes = mysqli_fetch_object($sqlClientes)){
            $visualizar .= "<tr>";
            $visualizar .= "<td style='font-weight: bold'><i class=\"fas fa-caret-right\"></i> ".$csClientes->NomeCompleto."</td>";
            $visualizar .= "<td style='text-align: center;'>R$ ".number_format($csClientes->ValorTotal,2,',','.')."</td>";
            $visualizar .= "<td style='text-align: center'><span class='status'><a href='#!' id='btnAlterar' data-id='".$csClientes->IdFinanceiro."' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs'>Pendente</a></span></td>";
            $visualizar .= "</tr>";
    }
```

**No JQuery**

```
<script>
$(document).on('click',"#btnAlterar", function(){
  var IdFinanceiro = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $.post('sistema/alterar-status.php', {key: IdFinanceiro}, function(retorno){
    if(retorno == 1){
      $(".status").html("<a href='#!' id='btnAlterar' data-id='<?php echo $csClientes->IdFinanceiro; ?>' class='btn btn-success btn-xs'>Pago</a>");
    }else{
      $(".status").html("<a href='#!' id='btnAlterar' data-id='<?php echo $csClientes->IdFinanceiro; ?>' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs'>Pendente</a>");
    }
    });
});
</script>
```

**PHP que altera o status**

```
$sql = mysqli_query($this->conexao,"UPDATE pagamentos SET StatusPagamento = 'P' WHERE IdPagamento = '".$_POST["key"]."';");
if(mysqli_affected_rows($this->conexao) > 0){
  echo '1';
}else{
  echo '0';
}
```

Quando clico no botão de **Fernando Pessoa**, ele não altera somente o dele, mas também de todos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Tentei também dessa forma:**

```
<script>
    $(document).on('click',"#btnAlterar", function(){
      var IdFinanceiro = $(this).attr('data-id');
        $.post('sistema/alterar-status.php', {key: IdFinanceiro}, function(retorno){
        if(retorno == 1){
           $("#statusPago").css('display','block');                             
           $("#statusAberto").css('display','none');
        }else{
           $("#statusAberto").css('display','block');
           $("#statusPago").css('display','none');
        }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

**E no HTML**

```
   <td style='text-align: center'>
        <span id='statusAberto' style='display: block'><a href='#!' id='btnAlterar' data-id="<?php echo $csClientes->IdFinanceiro; ?>" class='btn btn-danger btn-xs'>Pendente</a></span>
        <span id='statusPago' style='display: none'><a href='#!' id='btnAlterar' data-id="<?php echo $csClientes->IdFinanceiro; ?>" class='btn btn-success btn-xs'>Pago</a></span>
  </td>
```

Só que dessa vez ele altera o primeiro e não o de **Fernando Pessoa** quando clico:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Seu problema esta no retorno. Você esta trocando todos os elementos com a classe `.status`

Comment: Olá Edson. Não tenho muita experiência com JQuery. Poderia me dar um exemplo de como eu poderia aplicar da maneira correta?

Comment: Pode trocar para `$(that).parent(".status")`, mas pro funcionar  tem que declarar o `that` antes do `$.post()` assim: `var that = this`, se vc acessar o this direto dentro da função de retorno ele não vai achar

Comment: Perfeito Edson. Funcionou. Se quiser, coloca como Resposta que dou por aceito. Muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Vou adicionar valeu!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu problema está na linha `$(".status").html("<a href='#!' id='btnAlterar' data-id='<?php echo $csClientes->IdFinanceiro; ?>' class='btn btn-success btn-xs'>Pago</a>");`

Nesta linha você adiciona o html em todos os elementos da página que possuem a classe `.status`, para contornar isto você precisa identificar aqul o `<a>` que chamou a função e adicionar a classe no `.status` no pai: `$(that).parent(".status")`

Lembrando que você deve declarar uma variável fora do `$.post()` para que o `this` possa ser acessível dentro do callback: `var that = this;`

```
$(document).on('click',"#btnAlterar", function(){
  var that = this;
  var IdFinanceiro = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $.post('sistema/alterar-status.php', {key: IdFinanceiro}, function(retorno){
    if(retorno == 1){
      $(that).parent(".status").html("<a href='#!' id='btnAlterar' data-id='<?php echo $csClientes->IdFinanceiro; ?>' class='btn btn-success btn-xs'>Pago</a>");
    }else{
      $(that).parent(".status").html("<a href='#!' id='btnAlterar' data-id='<?php echo $csClientes->IdFinanceiro; ?>' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs'>Pendente</a>");
    }
    });
});
```